# Windows service does not start automatically (tried automatic delayed and both types of log on)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have a Windows service that starts fine when we manually start it, but when we set it to `automatic` or `automatic (delayed start)`, it (most of the time) refuses to start by itself.

The Logon is normally the domain account I have (myname@mycompany.com), but even when I set the Logon type to `Local System account`, the service fails to start by itself.

The service is a Quartz.NET job scheduling service but I am not sure how that should be relevant when I can start it manually. The service is written in C# using `.NET framework 4.5`.

**Update:** I realized my service is logging the following code when it fails to restart by itself:

```
2015-02-13 15:09:15,674 [1] ERROR Quartz.Server.QuartzServer [(null)] - Server initialization failed:Unable to bind scheduler to remoting.
Quartz.SchedulerException: Unable to bind scheduler to remoting. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CoreChannel.GetMachineIp()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel.SetupMachineName()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IServerChannelSinkProvider sinkProvider, IAuthorizeRemotingConnection authorizeCallback)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IClientChannelSinkProvider clientSinkProvider, IServerChannelSinkProvider serverSinkProvider)
   at Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter.RegisterRemotingChannelIfNeeded()
   at Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter.Bind(IRemotableQuartzScheduler scheduler)
   at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.Bind()
   at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.Initialize()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.Initialize()
   at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.Instantiate()
   at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.GetScheduler()
   at Quartz.Server.QuartzServer.Initialize() [See nested exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No such host is known
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CoreChannel.GetMachineIp()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel.SetupMachineName()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IServerChannelSinkProvider sinkProvider, IAuthorizeRemotingConnection authorizeCallback)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpChannel..ctor(IDictionary properties, IClientChannelSinkProvider clientSinkProvider, IServerChannelSinkProvider serverSinkProvider)
   at Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter.RegisterRemotingChannelIfNeeded()
   at Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter.Bind(IRemotableQuartzScheduler scheduler)
   at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.Bind()
   at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.Initialize()]
```

Comment: If a service is started (or an attempt is made) this is logged in the system event log with source "Service Control Manager". What does that say? Does your service log something somewhere when it starts (and if not, why not?)

Comment: do you have some logging in the service start so to understand if any error happens during startup? or do you find anything in the windows event log? I suggest to add some very verbose logging because in some cases it can depend on other services or connections to be established from / to that machine which are simply not available yet during system startup, we also have similar issues here...

Comment: @JeroenMostert please take a look at the update. The question has been flagged as duplicate but I cannot find my answer there either.